# MongoDB multiple access to same server

Tags: python, database, mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I've running MongoDB server locally, on a Windows Virtual Machine.
I have data coming from different plants. I guess the best and simplest choice is to create a DB for each plant.
More precisely, for each plant I have to create 3 different DBs to put different types of data (original data, processed data, analyzed data) of the same plant.
Actually I've created 3 DBs for each plant, linked to the same IP address and port, that are on the VM where the MongoDB service is running. The data folder of DB is on a server.
I've modified the mongod.cfg file in a way like this:

```
systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: \\server\db\MongoDB\Plants\log\mongod.log
storage:
    dbPath: \\server\db\MongoDB\Plants\data
net:
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.5.20
    port: 3415
```

I run more than one script in Python, accessing to different DBs, reading and writing, sometimes from different PCs on the same LAN. All the scripts are running 24/7 but are triggered once a hour, when new data arrive.
What I've seen is that sometimes, maybe when some script is running at the same time of another one, the execution become very slow and occasionally a time out error arise, stopping all the execution.
It needs to restart MongoDB service to clean the error.

What is the easiest and fast solution to avoid this problem? I heard about shard and replica set, but I'm not expert and I don't know if these are the best solutions for me. Are they the best choice? How may I configure the service in this case?

Thank you to who could help me.

Comment: Hi giube; could I clarify something with you? Do you have a single MongoDB service, with several separate databases? Or are you running multiple MongoDB services on the same server?

Comment: Hi Vince. I have a single MongoDB service, running on a Virtual machine (192.168.5.20) on the same LAN of other PCs. I have many (9-10) plants, each one with 3 different kind of data (original, processed, calculations) that I though to put on 3 different DBs. All these DBs (3 x number of plants) have been loaded, as far, on the single MongoDB service. I tried to separate the 3 DBs of each plant in different port on the same service on the same IP of the VM, but I didn't find a working solution.

Comment: I don't think your problem is one that needs a solution like sharding or replica sets. I think your problem is more to do with those scripts, and how much work they are making the server do. Maybe they are in conflict for the same database collections/documents? Or maybe they are simply making the server do so much work that it doesn't have the specs to do any more?

Comment: I will check it. I'm pretty sure there is no conflicts with the same database/collections/documents. It could be - as you hypothesized - some unuseful operation made in the scripts, that overloads the server or produce a timeout error.

Answer (score 0):

first try to identify what triggers the error, it may be slow because your scripts are doing some search and you may need to do some indexing.

also pay attention to indexes to not be bigger than your RAM memory

try to increase the amount of ram memory that your mongo DB has

Comment: Thank you, but I guess this is not the case. My scripts only read 1 document at once and write on DB. They also make some analysis and calculations, but "locally" on the machine, not on the DB.